# How can I rewrite a wordpress URL to use the first sub directory as a querystring?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, url-rewriting

I need the first sub-directory in my URL to rewrite to a querystringed URL if the category matches a program code ie: 4 upper case characters such as AUBU

For example, I would need:

http://www.georgiancollege.ca/devprograms/AUBU/

To rewrite to:

http://www.georgiancollege.ca/devprograms/index.php?page_id=16&major=AUBU

But I don't want it to affect current URLs such as

http://www.georgiancollege.ca/devprograms/a-to-z/

which **should not** be re-written to:

http://www.georgiancollege.ca/devprograms/index.php?page_id=16&major=a-to-z

Here is what I have so far which is not working at all. (based on: http://thereforei.am/2011/10/28/advanced-taxonomy-queries-with-pretty-urls/ )

```
function eg_add_rewrite_rules() {
global $wp_rewrite;

$new_rules = array(
    '(.+)/?$' => 'index.php?page_id=16&major=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1)
);
$wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'eg_add_rewrite_rules' );
```

UPDATE: The code above now redirects to the proper page, but on that page I can't read the querystring in, likely because of the URL rewrite the querystring isn't on the final page...

So using,

```
$program = $_GET['major'];
```

Doesn't return the major code...

Comment: How does the change .htaccess look like?

Comment: No change to .htaccess - I can't actually.

Comment: I highly suggest you make yourself more comfortable with the general topic then, you might be missing some fundamental basic knowledge about the commands you use: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite looks like a good read for a start in your case.

Comment: @hakre yes, thanks - I've read that page and it is possible to build rewrites without touching the .htaccess, thanks. I've got the rewrite working - the issue is that it's not passing the querystring data through.

Comment: Yes, that is true. However if it was not apache who re-wrote the URL, then PHP was called with a different URL which at that time didn't have the query variable `major` and therefore `$_GET` is not populated with that, right? So you must look into a different location for that *major* value. Sounds fair?

Comment: @hakre yes, see my answer below - I tried looking to $wp_query->query_vars as suggested on a similar problem - they used the exact same rewrite and were able to get their querystring out of the query_vars - for some reason, I was not able to get it from there either so I went with an entirely different approach that is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input.

I've had to use a 'work around' solution because it just doesn't seem to want to work.

I tried using $wp_query->query_vars to get the querystring data as opposed to $_GET or $_POST like so:

```
if(isset($wp_query->query_vars['major'])) {
    $program = urldecode($wp_query->query_vars['major']);
}
```

As suggested on: http://www.rlmseo.com/blog/passing-get-query-string-parameters-in-wordpress-url/ but the query_var for 'major' kept being non existent even though the pagename query var from the same URL rewrite did exist.

So I moved on...

Here is the new URL rewrite:

```
function add_rewrite_rules($aRules) {
  $aNewRules = array('([A-Z]{4})/outline/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=programs&major=$matches[1]');
  $aNewRules2 = array('([A-Z]{4})/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=programs&major=$matches[1]');
  $aRules = $aNewRules + $aNewRules2 + $aRules;
  return $aRules;
}
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules');
```

Since my URL rewrite is still keeping the program code in the URL just in a prettier way, I'm simply grabbing the REQUEST_URI and parsing out the program code like so:

```
$parts = explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if (isset($_GET['major'])) {
  $program = $_GET['major']; 
} elseif ($parts[1] == 'devprograms') {
  $program = $parts[2];
} else {
  $program = get_the_title();
}
```

This accounts for both link styles /devprograms/BUSN and /devprograms/programs?major=BUSN

The only downside to this is I cannot have other pages on the install with 4 letter names such as 'test' or 'page' as they will get rewritten to the programs page with 'test' or 'page' as the program code, which won't be actual programs. That is an issue that is easy to work around when naming pages though.

Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a hack for Apache url re-writing. I would go about this with [Mod_Rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/)
As for your code you are matching with a regular expression that is not specific enough. You only want to match 4 uppercase characters? Maybe try this instead:

```
'devprograms/([A-Z]{4})/?$' => 'index.php?page_id=16&major=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1)
```

Comment: thanks, that fixed the issue with pages like 'a-to-z' also getting matched, but I'm still unable to read the querystring on the page due to it not existing... So basically, I need the rewrite to post the page with the course code in the $_POST['major'] - any ideas?

Comment: Very odd. The querystring should be there. Maybe it's getting a double redirect? Try /index.php... note the slash in front of it.

Comment: I'm also a bit puzzled by the code. + operator does not merge arrays. it seems that $wp_rewrite->rules = array_merge($wp_rewrite->rules, $new_rules); would be better for combining rules.