# Wordpress Rewrite API to another domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am trying to add a rewrite rule to a Wordpress plugin I am developing which gets any images from Amazon S3. e.g:

`https://wordpresswebsite.com/images/image1.jpg` rewritten to `https://s3.location.amazonaws.com/images/image1.jpg`

I have been trying to use `add_rewrite_rule()` on the `init` hook as follows:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^images/(.*)?$', $s3_url, 'top');
```

I have also tried

```
global $wp_rewrite;
$wp_rewrite->add_external_rule('^images/(.*)?$', $s3_url);
```

The problem that I have is that in both circumstances, Wordpress is adding a preceding `/` before my URL, i.e; `/https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/images/image1.jpg` so it breaks the link.

Does anyone know if there is another way to do this using the Wordpress API or do I have to manually add the entry into .htaccess and figure out how to stop Wordpress then overwriting it?

Seems a bit silly if I have to do it manually as the functions I have tried are so close to working..

Thanks

Comment: I would try hooking into the mod_rewrite_rules filter and seeing what that outputs. Maybe you can modify your url there before it gets written to .htaccess by wordpress (which wordpress does for external redirects)

Comment: _“figure out how to stop Wordpress then overwriting it?”_ - not that much to figure out there, simply by placing it outside the BEGIN WORDPRESS / END WORDPRESS comments …

Comment: @JamesHamann - thanks for pointing this out, I forgot to mention in the original question I was running the above on the `init` hook. I have also tried running it on `mod_rewrite_rules` hook as you suggested but it does not seem to make a difference. I am wondering if this thread has the answer, but it is old and a bit hacky: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824334/adding-mod-rewrite-rules-programmatically-in-wordpress-plugin

Comment: @CBroe thanks - I figured this bit out at least :) unfortunately still stuck on the main problem...